# Error when pressing back button

Tags: android

In my android application when press back button show this errors in logcat :

```
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nabege/com.example.nabege.Edit_Collection_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at com.example.nabege.Edit_Collection_Activity.onCreate(Edit_Collection_Activity.java:30)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-01 14:07:42.995: E/AndroidRuntime(6279):     ... 11 more
```

my activity codes like this:

```
public class Edit_Collection_Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DB_Nabege_helper nabege_db = new DB_Nabege_helper(this);
    private EditText txt_update_collection;
    private Button btn_update_collection;
    private Button btn_cancel_update_collection;
    private int id_collection;
    private String name_collection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit__collection);

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        id_collection = extra.getInt("id_collection");
        name_collection = extra.getString("name_collection");

        //
        txt_update_collection = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_update_collection);
        txt_update_collection.setText(name_collection);
        // update collection
        btn_update_collection = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_update_collection);
        btn_update_collection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nabege_db.open();
                nabege_db.update_colletion(id_collection, txt_update_collection.getText().toString());
                nabege_db.close();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "تغییرات با موفقیت ثبت شد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //go To pre Activity
                goback();

            }
        });
        //go back
        btn_cancel_update_collection =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_update_collection_cancel);
        btn_cancel_update_collection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goback();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit__collection_, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
        private void goback() {
    super.finish();
}
}
```

I run the activity by The following codes in previous activity.
In previous activity is a list view that by click on the list view items show Dialog then by press button in this Dialog run The following code :

```
 edit_collection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goToEditCollectionActivity = new Intent(Collection_List_Activity.this, Edit_Collection_Activity.class);
            startActivity(goToEditCollectionActivity);
            goToEditCollectionActivity.putExtra("id_collection", id_tbl_collection[index_collection]);
            goToEditCollectionActivity.putExtra("name_collection", name_collection_tbl_collection[index_collection]);
            menu_collection_listDialog.cancel();
            startActivity(goToEditCollectionActivity);
        }
    });
```

Please  help

Comment: Why you call startActivity(goToEditCollectionActivity); twice?

Comment: We need to see method goback(); so post it @programmer1382000, and have you add activity on manifest.xml??

Comment: Error is you called startActivity(...) before and then you set all those extra so activity got called without putting that bundle iinformation and when you tried accessing those null values extras ,you got NullPointException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bundle is empty becuase you are calling activity before setting up all those resources

```
edit_collection.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent goToEditCollectionActivity = new Intent(Collection_List_Activity.this, Edit_Collection_Activity.class);
        goToEditCollectionActivity.putExtra("id_collection", id_tbl_collection[index_collection]);
        goToEditCollectionActivity.putExtra("name_collection", name_collection_tbl_collection[index_collection]);
        menu_collection_listDialog.cancel();
        startActivity(goToEditCollectionActivity);
    }
});
```

Also whenever you have to handle bundles always check

```
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null){
    //Do something
}else{
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Always happy to help :)